# RXJava: mapping fatal exception

Tags: java, android, rx-java, mvp

I'm downloading JSON array and mapping it into POJO using retrofit. I've successfully downloaded it but I have problem mapping it from API do domain object with rxJava.

This is my presenter:

```
 public class WeatherPresenterImpl extends BasePresenter implements WeatherPresenter {

private final NetworkStateUtil networkStateUtil;
private WeakReference<WeatherListView> viewWeakReference;
private final WeatherApi weatherApi ;
private final WeatherDataMapper weatherDataMapper;
private final Scheduler observeScheduler;
private final Scheduler subscribeScheduler;

public WeatherPresenterImpl(final NetworkStateUtil networkStateUtil, final WeatherApi weatherApi, final
                            WeatherDataMapper weatherDataMapper, final Scheduler subscribeScheduler, final Scheduler observeScheduler) {
    this.networkStateUtil = networkStateUtil;
    this.weatherApi = weatherApi;
    this.weatherDataMapper = weatherDataMapper;
    this.observeScheduler = observeScheduler;
    this.subscribeScheduler = subscribeScheduler;
}

@Override
public void activate(final WeatherListView viewWeakReference) {
    this.viewWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(viewWeakReference);
}

@Override
public void requestWeatherData(String city, String apiKey) {
    if (networkStateUtil.isConnected()) {

        addSubscription(weatherApi.getWeather(city, WeatherApi.APIKEY)
                                  .map(weatherDataMapper::map)
                                  .subscribeOn(subscribeScheduler)
                                  .observeOn(observeScheduler)
                                  .subscribe(this::onRequestCityDataOnNext, this::onRequestCityDataError));
    } else {
        ifViewNotNull(WeatherListView::showNoConnectionMessage);
        getDataFromDatabase();
    }
}

@Override
public void requestWeatherData() {
    Log.e("success","success");
}

private void onRequestCityDataError(final Throwable throwable) {
    Log.e("fail",throwable.getMessage());

}

private void onRequestCityDataOnNext(final List<WeatherData> weatherDatas) {

    ifViewNotNull((weatherListView) -> {
        weatherListView.setWeatherData(weatherDatas);
    });

}

private void ifViewNotNull(final Action1<WeatherListView> func) {
    final WeatherListView weatherListView = viewWeakReference.get();
    if (weatherListView != null) {
        func.call(weatherListView);
    }
}
```

this is my Mapper class:

```
public final class WeatherDataMapper {

public final List<WeatherData> map(final WeatherDataApi listWeatherDataApi) {

    List<WeatherData> weatherDataModelList = Collections.emptyList();

    final int numberOfDays = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDays; i++) {
        String tempMin = String.valueOf(KelvinConverterUtil.convertKelvinToCelsius(listWeatherDataApi.list.get(i).temp.min));
        String tempMax = String.valueOf(KelvinConverterUtil.convertKelvinToCelsius(listWeatherDataApi.list.get(i).temp.max));
        String cityName = listWeatherDataApi.city.name;
        String description = listWeatherDataApi.list.get(i).weather.get(0).description;
        String humidity = String.valueOf(listWeatherDataApi.list.get(i).humidity);
        String pressure = String.valueOf(listWeatherDataApi.list.get(i).pressure);
        String icon = String.valueOf(listWeatherDataApi.list.get(i).weather.get(0).icon);
        weatherDataModelList.add(i, new WeatherData(tempMin, tempMax, cityName, description, humidity, pressure, icon));
    }
    return weatherDataModelList;
}
}
```

And this is the Exception that I get when I run it:

```
10-18 17:42:48.700 14461-  14606/package.com.openweatherappE/AndroidRuntime:FATAL EXCEPTION: RxIoScheduler-2
                                                                      Process: package.com.openweatherapp, PID: 14461
                                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
                                                                          at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:62)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                                         Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError
                                                                          at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:192)
                                                                          at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
                                                                          at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:276)
                                                                          at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:219)
                                                                          at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:220)
                                                                          at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                       Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred. 
                                                                          at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:192) 
                                                                          at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120) 
                                                                          at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:276) 
                                                                          at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:219) 
                                                                          at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:220) 
                                                                          at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                       Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException$CompositeExceptionCausalChain: Chain of Causes for CompositeException In Order Received =>
                                                                          at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:338)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:61)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.-wrap0(RuntimeInit.java)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:86)
                                                                          at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                                          at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
                                                                          at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:66)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
                                                                          at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:404)
                                                                          at package.com.openweatherapp.model.WeatherDataMapper.map(WeatherDataMapper.java:27)
                                                                          at package.com.openweatherapp.presenter.WeatherPresenterImpl$$Lambda$1.call(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMap.java:66)
                                                                          at retrofit.RxSupport$2.run(RxSupport.java:56)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                          at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                       Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: package.com.openweatherapp.data.pojo.WeatherDataApi.class
                                                                          at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMap.java:70)
                                                                          at retrofit.RxSupport$2.run(RxSupport.java:56) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                          at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142) 
                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
                                                                          at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:232)
                                                                          at package.com.openweatherapp.presenter.WeatherPresenterImpl.onRequestCityDataError(WeatherPresenterImpl.java:61)
                                                                          at package.com.openweatherapp.presenter.WeatherPresenterImpl.access$lambda$1(WeatherPresenterImpl.java:0)
                                                                          at package.com.openweatherapp.presenter.WeatherPresenterImpl$$Lambda$3.call(Unknown Source)
                                                                          at rx.internal.util.ActionSubscriber.onError(ActionSubscriber.java:44)
                                                                          at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:157)
                                                                          at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:120)
                                                                          at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.checkTerminated(OperatorObserveOn.java:276)
                                                                          at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:219)
                                                                          at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:220)
                                                                        at     rx.in
10-18 17:42:48.744 14461-14610/package.com.openweatherapp I/Process: Sending     signal. PID: 14461 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `@Override
     public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String text) {
     weatherPresenter.requestWeatherData(text, WeatherApi.APIKEY);
                return false;
            }`



Basically in a fragment in a searchView. This was working for one a single WeatherData object but mapping to array gives me problems.

But I need array as I need to show data for 3 days.

Comment: `@Module
public final class ThreadingModule {

    public static final String OBSERVE_SCHEDULER = "Observe Scheduler";
    public static final String SUBSCRIBE_SCHEDULER = "Subscribe Scheduler";


    @Named(OBSERVE_SCHEDULER)
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public final Scheduler provideMainThreadScheduler() {
        return AndroidSchedulers.mainThread();
    }

    @Named(SUBSCRIBE_SCHEDULER)
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public final Scheduler provideIOScheduler() {
        return Schedulers.io();
    }
}
`

I'm using dagger2 to inject them

Comment: `Collections.emptyList();` -> read the manual.

Comment: wow I did exactly the same mistake as you did thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<WeatherData> weatherDataModelList = Collections.emptyList();
```

The resulting collection is immutable, hence you're getting an `UnsupportedOperationException`. On top of that, you get a
`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message` because in your `onRequestCityDataError` you fail to handle exceptions that don't have a message.